# Can I add a dependency reference programmatically to the calling assembly

Tags: c#, reflection

When a class library is executing, you have access to a few Assembly methods.

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
```

Each of these has a .GetReferencedAssemblies() method

If I call

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
```

I get a list of all the dependent libraries for the assembly the current class is within.

However my code has been called by an engine using reflection and it is actually the parent application that needs the dependency to be there.

```
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
```

Both give me the list of dependencies I need to add to.

However every method I have tried to programmatically add an assembly, eg Assembly.Load, Assembly.LoadFrom all only add it to the GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies() list, not the dependencies for the calling or entry assembly.

Is there a way to programmatically add an assembly to the references list of the calling or entry assembly, not the currently executing one?

Comment: Why don't you explain what you want to achieve with accessing referenced assemblies? Maybe there's a better approach for your underlying issue

Comment: Sure. I have an engine that has a config file. That config file specifies a list of assemblies and classes elsewhere that implement IRunnable. The engine then uses reflection to create a handle to the interface from the assembly/class name provided. It then executes the class using the IRunnable.Run() method. So my engine really just get passed a number of jobs to run, each in separate assemblies lying on separate machines that all implement a known interface. The engine then uses reflection to load and run these classes. However if the distributed job references something my engine does not..

Comment: So Job1 might be in an assembly that depends on JSON 7.0.0. My control engine that loads and runs Job 1 does not reference JSON 7.0.0 so when it executes Job 1 using reflection, it fails as JSON is not available. I need some way for the control engine to load the dependencies required before it executes the job in the distributed assembly

Comment: maybe you can solve this in a better way creating an `AppDomain` when you need to run a job, and when you create one you can pass which assemblies should be loaded (i.e. referenced assemblies) during run-time